# Run after all cucumber tests

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, cucumber

Is there a way to run a method after all of the cucumber tests have been run?

The @After annotation would run after every individual test, right? I wan't something that would only run once, but at the very end.

Answer (score 11):

You could use the standard JUnit annotations.

In your runner class write something similar to this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(format = {"html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json-pretty:target/cucumber-json-report.json"})
public class RunCukesTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        System.out.println("Ran the before");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void teardown() {
        System.out.println("Ran the after");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a solution that only involves executing tests from the cucumber Main class and not from a unit test?

Answer (score 3):

With TestNG suite annotations would work as well.

```
@BeforeSuite
public static void setup() {
    System.out.println("Ran once the before all the tests");
}

@AfterSuite
public static void cleanup() {
    System.out.println("Ran once the after all the tests");
}
```

Comment: This worked best for me. The `@BeforeSuite` didn't seem to trigger, though. (But I only needed the teardown).

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is to register event handler for `TestRunFinished` event. For that you can create a custom plugin which will register your hook for this event :

```
public class TestEventHandlerPlugin implements ConcurrentEventListener {

    @Override
    public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher eventPublisher) {
        eventPublisher.registerHandlerFor(TestRunFinished.class, teardown);
    }

    private EventHandler<TestRunFinished> teardown = event -> {
        //run code after all tests
    };
}
```

and then you will have to register the plugin :

- if you are running cucumber CLI you can use `-p`/`--plugin` option and pass fully qualified name of the java class : `your.package.TestEventHandlerPlugin`
- for Junit runner :

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = "your.package.TestEventHandlerPlugin") //set features/glue as you need.
public class TestRunner {

}
```

Comment: This answer is what worked for my cases as it does not require method to be static (comparing to top answer) and I may use dependency injection.

Answer (score -4):

cucumber is a scenario base test, you should write your own scenario in `.feature` file step by step and these steps are executed respectively by their step definitions.

So if you want something to happen after all steps, you should write it in the last step and develop this step in its step definition.

Also, for what you want to execute before other steps you should consider a step before all the steps in the `.feature` file and develop it in its step definition.

Comment: Sometimes there are things that need to happen to maintain the lifecycle of tests (ie start spring, destory spring context). These actions should not be part of a feature file. The feature is the front-end of the test. It should only be concern with explaining what is happening in the test. Not what is happening in the code.